# In iTunes 11, how do I download all existing shows for a podcast?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

Recently, I've started listening to more podcasts on my iPhone. I've found a few that I like and want to listen to past episodes. Ideally, I want to just download. I can't seem to figure out a way to queue up all unplayed episodes for download in iTunes.

I found in the settings for the podcast I can have it automatically download all *new* episodes, but this doesn't apply for older episodes.

Ideally, I don't want to have to click the download button for each episode (there are a couple hundred episodes).

Comment: For what its worth, I just want to state publicly somewhere that I hate the new iTunes 11 interface. It looks nice, but they broke the number #1 of good UX and that's to keep an interface which is familiar and consistent for the user.

Comment: start thinking different, do everything different :) You must enjoy breaking traditions and learning useless things!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Select the **List** tab:

   [image]
2. Click on the disclosure arrow to expand the subscription (if it's not already expanded):

   [image]
3. Click on the download button at the top of the list:

   [image]
4. Click **OK** to start downloading all episodes:

   [image]

Comment: This has worked for me in lists less than 100. If anyone finds a limit to the volume of data, the count of episodes, or another limit to this, please comment or edit.

Comment: I tried this on a 400+ episode subscription (Stuff You Should Know) and it downloads all of the items.

Comment: I see no such "download all" button in my iTunes 11.3 on MacOS 10.9.4.  http://i.imgur.com/SBTfSkh.png  I had to click on the "download from cloud" icon for each file/podcast individually (which takes a while for subscriptions that have many historical podcasts; eg, I can do click on 63 different episodes individually to get all the historical vimcasts downloaded, as per the aforementioned screenshot.).

Comment: In 12.2.3.34, in the `Episode List` view, there's no download button either. Right-clicking on the title of the show is (the row which acts as a parent for all the episodes) and selecting `Save Episode` (sic) did the trick. i.e.: all episodes got downloaded and I could finally synchronize all of the episodes with my iPod.

Comment: Things also depend on the podcast feed set up by the author of the podcast. If said show is setup to, say, show only the last 10 episodes, then older episodes won't be available for download. i.e.: see the official iTunes page for your podcast to see how many episodes are available, before concluding the issue lies with the iTunes software.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the podcast in your list of subscribed podcasts and there should be a "download all" option. Just found this myself after agonizingly clicking each download link for a few shows.
Addition:
The  list to click is  the  one  on  the  left side  of  the  screen,  not  with  all episodes open.  Didn't  work  on  screen  with  all  eps open,  does work  when only  left  side  list  is  seen. No  idea  why,  but  thanks  for  this, worked  for  me.

Comment: I had to use 'Save Episode' for it to work in iTunes 11.4  At the top of the Podcast list under 'list'.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the podcast settings (the gear icon in the standard podcasts view, or the *Settings…* button at the bottom in list view).
   [image: podcast settings]
2. In the second drop-down, select the podcast you want (or choose *Podcast Defaults* if you want to do this for every podcast).
3. Change the *When new episodes are available* setting to **Download all** and click **OK**.
4. Click the **Refresh** button for each podcast you want to download.

Comment: I tried to say in my question that I tried this. Doing this does not seem to download all *old* episodes, only episodes which are added from the moment I subscribe forward.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't go to "list"
2. Go to "My Podcast"
3. Select the podcast series you want on the left side
4. Click on any episode on the right
5. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all podcasts
6. Right click and find the "Download podcast" option

Don't do the "Save podcast" thing because it screwed up my podcasts in that there are now three different ways to view podcasts, some of them are still in my computer and iPad even after I deleted episodes.

Answer (score 1):

None of these suggestions worked for me. What *did* work for 11.4(18) 32bit Intel Core Duo (I am writing this on) was:

1. subscribe: it downloaded the latest episode.
2. right click (or popup menu, or two finger tap on the touch pad)
3. select "Mark as Unplayed"

Unfortunately, reproducing this to confirm the writing of this post has caused me to download 300 episodes of an unrelated 8 episode podcast I was trying to figure out.

**Edit: #2 above:**  right click on the podcast subscription title, not the episodes, though YMMV I have not tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Open iTunes and display your podcasts.  Near the top of the page you have the options to view All Unplayed, My Podcasts, My Stations, or List.  Select **My Podcasts**.

Choose the podcast you want to download.  In the pane to the right, you have the options  Unplayed, Feed, or Saved.  Select **Feed**. This will show all available podcasts for download.  Click on each cloud icon and go have lunch while you wait for the downloads to complete.